# Encouraging Technophilia

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, EDI has a body. And Joker's interest is... well he's interested. And, in the couple of discussions I've had with EDI so far, she doesn't seem to be opposed. But I love to play the matchmaker and see new love blossom (and I do really want to see this ridiculousness), so how do I make sure that the two are united in human-robot love? Is there any conversations that I need to make sure I don't miss along the way? Would there be any way, heaven forbid, for me to accidentally CPU-clock-block, as it were?

Comment: I believe the term is CPU-clock-block

Comment: @BenBrocka I apologize. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually, Joker will send an Email to Shepard asking to meet the commander in Purgatory. This is when you can convince him to go for it (or *not* go for it). There's no beating about the bush, Joker asks for your opinion, and you give it.

Or as my Shep said: "Why not?"

Comment: So there isn't really a way for me to mess it up before then?

Comment: @Ktash as long as you keep talking to both Joker and EDI... nope!